# Web page with a tab that doesn't show up in IE, but does in Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I am developing a webpage [www.seefinaviation.com](http://www.seefinaviation.com) which has a tabbutton **Online brochure...** on the top of the page. This button is shown in Google Chrome, but not in IE.

The disappearance only relates to the **Meet the team** and **Aircraft available** tabs. In other tabs the tabbutton **Online brochure...** is visible.

Also, on my desktop it doesn't appear in IE, but on my laptop it does (both use Windows 7 and IE10).

I have compared the code in the different modules and can't see the difference and have run out of ideas.

Does anybody know why this happens?

Comment: Is it because the width of the browser does not allow for that button to appear. If you resize the width of your browser so its smaller, you will see that the button disappears

Comment: It is *totally normal* that the same website *looks differently* in *different* browsers.

Comment: "On my desktop it doesn't appear in IE". "I find it defies my logic". *Oh hunny.*

Comment: There is more that doesn't work with that website in internet explorer BTW: http://i.stack.imgur.com/HpIsh.png

Comment: Thanks for your comments, Lee, Hakre & Wayne. Could you please elaborate on "There is more that doesn't work..." Hakre?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last `li` element doesn't fit in the same line and goes to new one. It is not visible though, because its parent `<div id="navigation_menu">` has fixed height. If you remove

```
height: 60px;
```

from `#navigation_menu` you'll see that the last `li` is present in new line. To put it in the same line as the others change the styling of the `li`s so they could all fit in the standard resolution. At this moment they need *1263px* to fit in one line.

Comment: You are right about the width. I decided just to shorten the wording in the tab and that will solve the problem until I have to put in a new tab. Adjusting the height does put it on a new line, but would also need a couple of other tweaks to get it looking pretty again. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

> On my desktop it doesn't appear in IE but on my laptop it does (both use Windows 7 and IE V 10)

In situations like this, it almost always turns out to be compatibility mode causing the problem.

Please check the IE dev tools in both of your IE10 browsers, and look at the browser mode. It is likely that one of them is falling into IE7-compatibility mode. This can easily happen in one copy of IE10 and not another due to browser config.

Try adding

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

...to your HTML head. This should force it to always use the best rendering mode, and avoid compatibility mode.

Hope that helps.